# Broadcast message when a contact is added or updated

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-broadcast

What`s the best possible way to know when a contact is added or updated in android?
My scenario is that i have to send contacts to server when a contact is added or updated.I want to know when a new contact is added or upated.

Comment: see ContentResolver class, pay special attention to content observers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no system broadcast when a new contact is added or changed. The `ContactsContract` observer [should notice such changes](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/) but due to a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39698) it doesn't work.

There's a workaround, though: when you look up your contacts in the [`RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) table, you have a [`DIRTY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#DIRTY) column which is `1` if the contact was changed since the last sync.

What you need to do is query the column for all values that are `1` and get the corresponding contact. If you wish to do this in the background, you could use a `Service`, possibly in conjuction with a timer to periodically poll the `DIRTY` column.